# Run a Google Apps Script using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, curl

I have a command in cURL that allows me to run a Google Apps Script:

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"function": "##function name##", "parameters": ["##MainDocID##", ["##Doc1ID##","##Doc2ID##","##Doc3ID##"]], devMode: false}' \
"https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run"
```

This script calls a function that is responsible for creating a folder in Google Drive and copying into the folder an edited and modified sheet file with certain values. The script works perfectly if I run it from the terminal.

I'm creating a web application and I want to include this script in a button that when clicked triggers the Apps Script function. To do this I want to convert this cURL command to javascript. I have used this converter ([REQBIN](https://reqbin.com/req/javascript/c-wyuctivp/convert-curl-to-javascript)) and got this code but no matter how many times I run it, it does not work correctly.

Converted javascript code:

```
var url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ### access token ###");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

var data = '{"function": "##function name##", "parameters": ["##MainDocID##", ["##Doc1ID##","##Doc2ID##","##Doc3ID##"]], devMode: false}';

xhr.send(data);
```

After creating the button and adding the javascript code, I have tested if it works but it doesn't because I check in Google Drive and the folder has not been created and the file I edit has not been copied. I have not been able to find out the exact error. From the web browser (client side) I get the response code '200' and in Google Cloud (logging operations), I get nothing but the only sure thing is that the function has not been executed.

Why is it not working?. Is the javascript code correct?. Could anyone help me, please?.

Thank you very much,
Wardiam

Comment: Of course not! Even though GAS is JS you must understand the differences in implementation of certain APIs. XHR does not exist in GAS. You have to use `UrlFetchApp`. If you still can't do it, then come back with another question

Comment: Two questions: (1) I assume the code is being run from JavaScript outside of GAS (e.g. in a web page, or node app, etc). Correct me if that is wrong. (2) Can you clarify what exactly happens? What does "not working" mean here? Any errors you can share?

Comment: The code is executed when a button is clicked in a web application. I have not been able to find out the exact error. From the web browser (client side) I get the response code '200' and in Google Cloud (login operations) I get nothing but the only sure thing is that the script call does not work because the scheduled action is not performed.

Comment: Thank you for the notes. Can you [edit] your question and add this new information in the body of the question, instead of in a comment (for better visibility)? Also what do you mean by "the scheduled action", in this case? I would expect a scheduled action to run without needing a user to click a button.

Comment: I have already included all the information to make my problem clearer. Thanks @andrewjames